# WordPress 301 Redirect Spaces to Hypens

Tags: wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have the following in my .htaccess file:

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /entertainment/
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\s|%20)
 RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 [N,DPI]
 RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /entertainment/index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

The problem is that domain.com/entertainment/testing 1/ redirects to domain.com/testing-1 instead of domain.com/entertainment/testing-1/. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[DPI]` flag used means discard path info. Hence, the rewrite base isn't taking effect. Either use

```
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Or, append the directory name to the rewrite rule as

```
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ /entertainment/$1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]
```